# Can I use another parameter in an unbiased estimator?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Given a multinomial distribution, the task is to make an unbiased estimator for one parameter. However, the parameters all add up to 1, so how can I make an unbiased estimator without using other parameters. Am I allowed to use other parameters?

Comment: Can you explain your problem in a more detailed manner? Your question seems very general for us to help you

Comment: So there is an event (X(i)) that can either succeed, fail or neither. The event occurs n times. X(i) = 0 if failed, 1 if neither and 2 if success. The parameters for the probability of each event occurring is labeled L1, L2, L3. So L1+L2+L3=1. I need to come up with an unbiased estimator for L1.

Comment: Thanks. Think about a binomial event for simplicity. Probabilities are $p$ and $q$, respectively. Then $p+q=1$. In principle if you know $q$ then you know $p$, and using that the expectation is linear then given an unbiased estimator for $q$ you would have an unbiased estimator for $p$ as well. In that sense, $p$ and $q$ are not independent. The same happens with your multinomial distribution

Comment: I see what you mean but with binomial I can simply adjust the event results so that it is bernoulli and then the sample mean will give me an estimator, but I don't know how to do that here.

Comment: Just relabel the events as $X=0$ and $X\neq 0$

Comment: So I totally understand your thinking there but how would I put my unbiased estimator in terms of the original values then. As in I could set an event such that W = 0 and W≠0, but how could I create an estimator using X(i) then.

Comment: See the answer I provided

Answer (score 0):

Think about a binomial  for simplicity. Probabilities are $p$ and $q$, respectively. Then $p+q=1$. In principle if you know $q$ then you know $p$, and using that the expectation is linear then given an unbiased estimator for $q$ you would have an unbiased estimator for $p$ as well. In that sense, $p$ and $q$ are not independent. The same happens with your multinomial distribution. In that case an unbiased estimator for $L_1$ would be the sample proportion of observations where $X=1$. That is

$\hat{L}_1=\sum 1_{X(i)=0}/n$

Notice that $1_{X(i)=0}$ has a Bernoulli distribution with probability $L_1$ and the rest follows from there.

Comment: This makes sense, but it isn't an equation without conditionals. Is there a way to do it without conditions such as the estimator equals the mean. Because I don't know how to calculate variance for this.

Comment: I am not sure, you probably can do it "without conditionals". However, notice that since you are working with a Bernoulli RV the variance is just $\hat{L}_1 *(1-\hat{L}_1)$.